# Prove that $f$ is continuous for $x\geq 1/2$ and strictly increasing 0n $[1,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis

I found this question [$f(x)=[x]+(x−[x])^{[x]}$ prove that this function is continuous for $x\ge 1/2$ and increase in $[1,+ ∞)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037136/fx-xx%e2%88%92xx-prove-that-this-function-is-continuous-for-x-ge-1-2-a)  but  i did not understant the  answer

Consider

$$f(x)=[x]+(x−[x])^{[x]}$$
where $[x]$ is the floor function.
 show that $f$ is continuous for $x\geq 1/2$ and strictly increasing  0n $[1,\infty)$.

My  attempt :  i take  $f(x)  = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if  x} \in [1/2,n) \\ n + (x-n)^n \ \text{if  x }\in [n, n +1) , n \in \mathbb{N} \end{cases}$

After that im not  able to show  that $f$ is continuous for $x\geq 1/2$ and strictly increasing  0n $[1,\infty)$.

any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: To show continuity just calculate $f(n+)$ and $f(n-)$.

Comment: @Kavi sir  yes   i got $\lim_{x \rightarrow n ^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow n^-}f(x) = n$ but how to show that  it is strictly increasing on $[1, \infty)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_1  \in [n-1,n)$ and $x_2 \in [n,n+1)$, then $f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2-n)^n + (1-(x_1-n+1)^{n-1} > (x_2 -n)^n \ge 0$

Hence  $f$   is strictly  increasing  on $[n, n+1)$